# How can I synchronize Solution Explorer’s folder structure with the one in my file system (where the solution belongs)?

Tags: visual-studio, filesystems, visual-studio-2019, sln-file

This problem appears after moving or renaming projects or folders via Solution Explorer in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. Is there a way to automatically synchronize Solution Explorer’s structure with the file system structure?

This is what my Solution Explorer looks like:

[image: mvs solution explorer view (the one I want to achieve in file system)]

But this is what the corresponding top-level directory in the file system has in it:

[image: File system view (mess with previous names and even deleted directories)]

Comment: Not at the _Solution_ level. If you use the new(ish) Visual Studio 2017 project format, then Visual Studio will, by default, rely on the file system as the file manifest, and display all files from within project folders. But, at the Solution level, it will only display projects and standalone files that are explicitly listed in your `.sln` file.

Comment: thanks for reply @JeremyCaney. Wish one day microsoft will add some feature to make it much easier to maintain mess in solution folder.

Comment: Indeed! There’s a lot of grumbling over the `*sln` format, and I’ve heard folks on the .NET team lament that it didn’t get revisited alongside the Visual Studio 2017 project format. Part of the issue is that it supports a lot of different project types, including many legacy formats. But I’m sure those issues are not insurmountable. You can vote for [a proposal to revisit the Solution format](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/643077/new-format-for-solution-sln-files.html) on Microsoft’s [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/).